# Looking for a more efficiency pandas code use BLS data set

Tags: python, pandas, performance, large-data

Looking for a more effective way to prep data for Kmeans analysis. Using the BLS ( Bureau of Labor Statistics ) and trying to learn Kmeans, I am doing the first pass of the data and want to add two columns, percentage of change over time per in median salary and tote employment.  The formula is a simply (((current year, state and occ_code)  minus the (min of those fourteen data points) / divided by (same min ) ... (( current year, occ_code   - min) / min *100), add two columns to dataframe. The data set is ~500K rows by 24 columns.  the code is run about 400 rows per min.... current expected to take about 24 hours for a full run,  thus the question.  Thank you

The sample data is here:
Any columns will work, I am just using a_median and tot_emp

`Unnamed: 0  area    st  state   occ_code    occ_title   tot_emp emp_prse    h_mean  a_mean  ... h_pct75 h_pct90 a_pct10 a_pct25 a_median    a_pct75 a_pct90 year    tot_emp_growth  a_median_growth
128037  128037  31  NE  Nebraska    25-2022 Middle school teachers, except special and voc...   3720    4.9 0   45270   ... 0   0   32850   37160   44220   53170   62120   2008    25.566343   0.0
491755  491755  19  IA  Iowa    47-2131 Insulation Workers, Floor, Ceiling, and Wall    360 18  19.59   40750   ... 23.56   27.98   27160   32230   38920   49010   58190   2018    25.566343   0.0
470924  470924  42  PA  Pennsylvania    19-1021 Biochemists and Biophysicists   1330    24  43.69   90880   ... 50.04   67.42   52300   64700   84400   104070  140240  2017    25.566343   0.0
267336  267336  20  KS  Kansas  39-4031 Morticians, Undertakers, and Funeral Directors  460 25.4    16.6    34540   ... 23.98   27.83   20400   21730   23950   49880   57890   2012    25.566343   0.0
491263  491263  19  IA  Iowa    11-9033 Education Administrators, Postsecondary 2360    6.8 51.81   107760  ... 61.22   86.07   52120   68670   93650   127330  179020  2018    25.566343   0.0
5 rows × 24 columns`

The code currently being tested is:

```
def occ_code_growths(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        cols_lit = ['year', 'occ_code', 'st' , 'tot_emp', 'a_median']
        df_lookup = df.lookup(list([df.index[i]]*len(cols_lit)), cols_lit)

        idx_emp_min = df[(df['occ_code'] == df_lookup[1]) & (df['st'] == df_lookup[2]) ]\
                        ['tot_emp'].values.astype(int).min()
        idx_median_min = df[(df['occ_code'] == df_lookup[1]) & (df['st'] == df_lookup[2]) ]\
                        ['a_median'].values.astype(int).min()

        idx_emp = df[(df['occ_code'] == df_lookup[1]) & (df['st'] == df_lookup[2]) \
                       & (df['year'] == df_lookup[0])  ]['tot_emp'].values.astype(int)
        idx_median = df[(df['occ_code'] == df_lookup[1]) & (df['st'] == df_lookup[2]) \
                       & (df['year'] == df_lookup[0])  ]['a_median'].values.astype(int)


        df['tot_emp_growth'] = float((((idx_emp  - idx_emp_min) / idx_emp_min) * 100)[0])
        df['a_median_growth'] = float((((idx_median - idx_median_min) / idx_median_min) * 100)[0])


        if i % 200 == 0 :
            print(df.index[i])

    return(df)

df_4 = occ_code_growths(df)

df_4.to_csv('./data/kmeans.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is cleaner but still slow code for ~500K rows by 25 columns. It still takes hours.  If someone has a faster answer please share.

```
df_6 =[[]]
def occ_code_growths(df, df_6):
    df_occ_unique = df.occ_code.unique()
    #    print(df_occ_unique)
    df_st_unique = df.st.unique()
    #    print(df_st_unique)
    df_year_unique = df.year.unique()
    #    print(df_yr_unique)
    df_6 = pd.DataFrame({ 'idx_row': [], 'tot_growth': [], 'median_growth': [], 'code': [], 'st': [], 'yr': []})
#     for i in range(len(df)):
#         print('i',i)
    for code in range(len(df_occ_unique)):
#        print('code',code)
        for st in range(len(df_st_unique)):
#            print('st',st)

            try:
                idx_emp_min = df[(df['occ_code'] == df_occ_unique[code]) & (df['st'] == df_st_unique[st]) ]['tot_emp'].values.astype(int).min()
                idx_median_min = df[(df['occ_code'] == df_occ_unique[code]) & (df['st'] ==  df_st_unique[st]) ]['a_median'].values.astype(int).min()
            except:
                print('Error with', tot_emp_growth, a_median_growth, df_occ_unique[code], df_st_unique[st], df_year_unique[yr].astype(int) )


            for yr in range(len(df_year_unique)):
#                print('yr',yr)
                try:
                    idx_emp = df[(df['occ_code'] == df_occ_unique[code]) & (df['st'] == df_st_unique[st])  \
                                   & (df['year'] == df_year_unique[yr])  ]['tot_emp'].values.astype(int)
                    idx_median = df[(df['occ_code'] == df_occ_unique[code]) & (df['st'] == df_st_unique[st])  \
                                   & (df['year'] == df_year_unique[yr])  ]['a_median'].values.astype(int)
                    idx_row = df[(df['occ_code'] == df_occ_unique[code]) & (df['st'] == df_st_unique[st])  \
                                   & (df['year'] == df_year_unique[yr])  ].index.values.astype(int)
                except:
                    print('Error with', tot_emp_growth, a_median_growth, df_occ_unique[code], df_st_unique[st], df_year_unique[yr].astype(int) )

                try:
                    tot_emp_growth = float((((idx_emp  - idx_emp_min) / idx_emp_min) * 100)[0])
                    a_median_growth = float((((idx_median - idx_median_min) / idx_median_min) * 100)[0])
                    df_6 = df_6.append({'idx_row': idx_row, 'tot_growth': tot_emp_growth, \
                                        'median_growth': a_median_growth, 'code': df_occ_unique[code], \
                                        'st':  df_st_unique[st], 'yr': df_year_unique[yr].astype(int) }, ignore_index=True)
                except:
                    print('Error with', tot_emp_growth, a_median_growth, df_occ_unique[code], df_st_unique[st], df_year_unique[yr].astype(int) )
#            print(df_6)

#    if i % 200 == 0 :
#        print(df.index[i])

    return(df, df_6)

df_5, df_7 = occ_code_growths(df, df_6)
```